# least squares regression to fit circle with constrained centre point

Tags: python, math

I have a set of points describing a curve. I need to find the best fit circle for this curve whilst keeping the x coordinate of centre of the circle fixed. I.e the only variables for this circle will be the radius and the y coordinate of the centre of the circle.
I've tried using some examples from the scipy cookbook which give me a very nice best fit circle (http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Least_Squares_Circle) but I'm not sure how I need to change this to set the x coordinate of the centre of the circle to a fixed value?

```
def fit_circ(xy, method):
    xy = array(xy)
    u = array(xy[:,0])
    v = array(xy[:,1])
  

    if method == 1:
#method_1 = 'algebraic'
# linear system defining the center in reduced coordinates (uc, vc):
#    Suu * uc +  Suv * vc = (Suuu + Suvv)/2
#    Suv * uc +  Svv * vc = (Suuv + Svvv)/2
# coordinates of the barycenter
        x_m = mean(u)
        y_m = mean(v)

# calculation of the reduced coordinates
        u = u - x_m
        v = v - y_m

        Suv  = sum(u*v)
        Suu  = sum(u**2)
        Svv  = sum(v**2)
        Suuv = sum(u**2 * v)
        Suvv = sum(u * v**2)
        Suuu = sum(u**3)
        Svvv = sum(v**3)

# Solving the linear system
        A = array([ [ Suu, Suv ], [Suv, Svv]])
        B = array([ Suuu + Suvv, Svvv + Suuv ])/2.0
        xc_1, yc_1 = linalg.solve(A, B)


# Calculation of all distances from the center (xc_1, yc_1)
        Ri_1      = sqrt((u-xc_1)**2 + (v-yc_1)**2)
        R_1       = mean(Ri_1)
        residu_1  = sum((Ri_1-R_1)**2)
        residu2_1 = sum((Ri_1**2-R_1**2)**2)
        
        xc_1 = x_m + xc_1
        yc_1 = y_m + yc_1

        
        return xc_1, yc_1, R_1, 0, residu_1
```

I have given some example data below. Very grateful for any help!

```
array([[  0, 128],
       [  1, 128],
       [  2, 128],
       [  3, 128],
       [  4, 127],
       [  5, 127],
       [  6, 127],
       [  7, 127],
       [  8, 126],
       [  9, 126],
       [ 10, 126],
       [ 11, 125],
       [ 12, 125],
       [ 13, 125],
       [ 14, 124],
       [ 15, 124],
       [ 16, 124],
       [ 17, 124],
       [ 18, 124],
       [ 19, 124],
       [ 20, 124],
       [ 21, 124],
       [ 22, 124],
       [ 23, 124],
       [ 24, 125],
       [ 25, 125],
       [ 25, 126],
       [ 26, 126],
       [ 26, 127],
       [ 27, 127],
       [ 28, 128],
       [ 29, 129],
       [ 29, 130],
       [ 30, 130],
       [ 30, 131],
       [ 31, 131],
       [ 32, 132],
       [ 33, 133],
       [ 34, 134],
       [ 35, 134],
       [ 35, 135],
       [ 36, 135],
       [ 37, 135],
       [ 38, 136],
       [ 46, 136],
       [ 47, 135],
       [ 48, 135],
       [ 49, 135],
       [ 50, 135],
       [ 51, 135],
       [ 52, 134],
       [ 53, 134],
       [ 54, 134],
       [ 55, 133],
       [ 56, 133],
       [ 57, 133],
       [ 58, 132],
       [ 59, 132],
       [ 60, 131],
       [ 61, 131],
       [ 62, 130],
       [ 63, 130],
       [ 64, 129],
       [ 65, 129],
       [ 66, 129],
       [ 67, 128],
       [ 68, 128],
       [ 69, 128],
       [ 70, 127],
       [ 71, 127],
       [ 72, 127],
       [ 73, 126],
       [ 74, 126],
       [ 75, 126],
       [ 76, 126],
       [ 77, 125],
       [ 78, 125],
       [ 79, 125],
       [ 80, 124],
       [ 81, 124],
       [ 82, 124],
       [ 83, 123],
       [ 84, 123],
       [ 85, 123],
       [ 86, 122],
       [ 87, 122],
       [ 88, 121],
       [ 89, 121],
       [ 90, 120],
       [ 91, 120],
       [ 92, 119],
       [ 93, 119],
       [ 94, 118],
       [ 95, 118],
       [ 96, 117],
       [ 97, 117],
       [ 98, 116],
       [ 99, 115],
       [ 99, 116],
       [100, 115],
       [101, 114],
       [102, 114],
       [103, 113],
       [104, 113],
       [105, 112],
       [106, 111],
       [106, 112],
       [107, 111],
       [108, 110],
       [109, 110],
       [110, 109],
       [111, 109],
       [112, 108],
       [113, 108],
       [114, 107],
       [115, 106],
       [115, 107],
       [116, 106],
       [117, 105],
       [118, 105],
       [119, 104],
       [120, 104],
       [121, 103],
       [122, 103],
       [123, 102],
       [124, 102],
       [125, 102],
       [126, 101],
       [127, 101],
       [128, 100],
       [129, 100],
       [130,  99],
       [131,  99],
       [132,  98],
       [133,  98],
       [134,  97],
       [135,  97],
       [136,  96],
       [137,  96],
       [138,  95],
       [139,  95],
       [140,  95],
       [141,  94],
       [142,  94],
       [143,  93],
       [144,  93],
       [145,  92],
       [146,  92],
       [147,  91],
       [148,  91],
       [149,  90],
       [150,  90],
       [151,  89],
       [152,  89],
       [153,  88],
       [154,  88],
       [155,  87],
       [156,  87],
       [157,  86],
       [158,  85],
       [158,  86],
       [159,  85],
       [160,  84],
       [161,  83],
       [161,  84],
       [162,  83],
       [163,  82],
       [164,  81],
       [164,  82],
       [165,  80],
       [165,  81],
       [166,  80],
       [167,  79],
       [168,  78],
       [168,  79],
       [169,  77],
       [169,  78],
       [170,  77],
       [171,  76],
       [172,  75],
       [172,  76],
       [173,  74],
       [173,  75],
       [174,  73],
       [174,  74],
       [175,  72],
       [175,  73],
       [176,  70],
       [176,  71],
       [177,  69],
       [177,  70],
       [178,  68],
       [178,  69],
       [179,  67],
       [179,  68],
       [180,  66],
       [180,  67],
       [181,  64],
       [181,  65],
       [182,  56],
       [182,  57],
       [182,  58],
       [182,  59],
       [182,  60],
       [182,  61],
       [182,  62],
       [182,  63],
       [183,  54],
       [183,  55],
       [184,  53],
       [184,  54],
       [185,  52],
       [185,  53],
       [186,  52],
       [187,  51],
       [188,  51],
       [189,  50],
       [190,  50],
       [191,  49],
       [192,  49],
       [193,  49],
       [194,  48],
       [195,  47],
       [195,  48],
       [196,  47],
       [197,  46],
       [198,  45],
       [198,  46],
       [199,  44],
       [199,  45],
       [200,  43],
       [200,  44],
       [201,  42],
       [201,  43],
       [202,  41],
       [202,  42],
       [203,  39],
       [203,  40],
       [204,  37],
       [204,  38],
       [205,  36],
       [205,  37],
       [206,  34],
       [206,  35],
       [207,  32],
       [207,  33],
       [208,  30],
       [208,  31],
       [209,  29],
       [209,  30],
       [210,  27],
       [210,  28],
       [211,  26],
       [211,  27],
       [212,  24],
       [212,  25],
       [213,  23],
       [213,  24],
       [214,  22],
       [214,  23],
       [215,  21],
       [215,  22],
       [216,  19],
       [216,  20],
       [217,  18],
       [217,  19],
       [218,  17],
       [218,  18],
       [219,  15],
       [219,  16],
       [220,  14],
       [220,  15],
       [221,  12],
       [221,  13],
       [222,  10],
       [222,  11],
       [223,   7],
       [223,   8],
       [223,   9],
       [224,   6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can keep the x coordinate of the circle fixed by replacing the linear system solve

```
xc_1, yc_1 = linalg.solve(A, B)
```

with

```
xc_1 = x_fixed - x_m
yc_1 = A[:, 1].dot(B - A[:, 0] * xc_1) / A[:, 1].dot(A[:, 1])
```

in which "x_fixed" is the circle's x coordinate that we specify, and all else is the same as before.

Explanation: rather than solving for xc_1, we're setting it according to x_fixed and finding the least squares fit for yc_1 on the reduced system. For further details on what this system means, see the derivation in ["Least-Squares Circle Fit" by Randy Bullock](http://dtcenter.org/sites/default/files/community-code/met/docs/write-ups/circle_fit.pdf).

With your test data, here is the resulting fit for a couple different values for x_fixed:

```
xc_1     yc_1     R_1  residu_1
-------------------------------
10.0  -116.02  247.66   2710.54
35.0   -71.07  199.45   2866.73
```

[image: A couple plots]